# how to solve Dimension too large error in \includegraphics

Tags: floats

I get an error saying Dimension too large while trying to compile the following code. Please help

```
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=5.76cm,width=2cm]{alawaysfalse1}
\caption{True Positive Rate (TPR) Vs No. of hops}
\label{figurealawaysfalse1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your requested picture height is massive: 576 cm = 5.76 m is too big for TeX. I suspect this is simply a typo.

Comment: even though i reduce the dimension, i get the same error

Comment: Please edit the question to show the update you've made:if that is for example `5.76cm` all will be fine. (Using `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` will show that without needing access to your image.)

Comment: using this package, there is no error. But i get a black image and not my image.                              \documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran} \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=2.5in,width=3.4in]{alawaysfalse1}
\caption{True Positive Rate (TPR) Vs No. of hops}
\label{figurealawaysfalse1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

Comment: The `demo` option is just there as we don't have your image, so allows testing. You don't need it for your real use case but the point was that there is no error here unless there is something very odd (corrupt) about the image file itself.